# Why does a star die once it has iron?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, stars, binding-energy, stellar-physics

I found out that iron is the death element for stars, but I couldn't find why can anyone knowledgeable on stars explain why iron causes the star to die?

Comment: by simple research, https://futurism.com/what-happens-when-stars-produce-iron

Comment: Related, but it doesn't exactly answer your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80256/  Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79355/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/215769/ and from our sister site https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2231/

Comment: I would like it if people that down-vote explain rather than just annoy me by not helping me improve it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the binding energy of some elements as a function of their number of nucleons

[image]

Since fusion leads to a higher number of nucleons, what a star does is to progressively move from left to right on this plot.

So if you start on the left, say H, you merge two, and the result has a larger binding energy, so energy is released. But that behavior is broken when you reach Fe$^{56}$, at that point, you need extra energy. Since the star cannot produce it, it stops fusing material, and it dies off

Comment: @Luna Glad it was of help

Comment: @Luna It can be frustrating, sorry you had a bad experience with your first post

Comment: my bet is they down-voted thinking this person is crazy

Comment: @Luna The site has a strong policy against homework-type questions which, in my humble opinion, ends up being a bit counterproductive. But ... it is what it is. Maybe that's the reason some users decided to downvote your post (just guessing), I just hope this doesn't discourage you from keep posting your questions as it really helps growing the community

Comment: except the first question was not homework type or my last one plus I am in earth science not physics so homework type is: why is magnetite magnetic, in my case

Comment: it was on topic it was closed as was unclear

Comment: @Luna I understand that, that's what I mean by counterproductive. Because some users prefer just to jump the guns and down-vote, or mark as off-topic, instead of taking the time to see the value in the question.

Comment: wow, have you seen my rep has been skyrocketing?

Comment: This is not the whole story. For example, if you add an alpha particle to a 56Ni nucleus, then this produces heat. Neither does the fact that fusion ceases cause the star to "die", unless you also regard a white dwarf as "dead". If "death" here refers to core-collapse and possibly a supernova, then the causes are different.

Answer (score 0):

A star "dies" when the fusion stops. 56Fe is the most stable nucleus that exists so it is the ultimate fusion product. Any nucleons contained in it no longer contribute to the energy production.