# $N$ point charges on a sphere

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, variational-principle, geometry

When charges are released on sphere, what is the shape made by charges?

Two charges are on opposite points of one diameter of the sphere.

Three charges make a shape of an equilateral triangle.

Four charges gives tetrahedron.

What shall five and more give?

Comment: Related MO.SE question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/187063/13917

Comment: @Qmechanic I'll just add that the main important result from that question was $N^2/2$ is the $1/r$ summation for uniformly distributed, infinite, points.  I'm having fun with some of the links posted here, they do indeed limit to the N^2/2, but there are some interesting lower order terms, not to mention some deviations that can't be approximated with calculus approaches, which is fascinating.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem with $N$ point charges on a sphere is a famous problem in electrostatics known as the *Thomson problem.* For large $N$, it is in general an open problem still under active research.

References:

1. [Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem)
2. [Mathworld.wolfram.com](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThomsonProblem.html)
3. [Mathpages.com](https://mathpages.com/home/kmath005/kmath005.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This has been a problem since Thomson proposed the arrangement of electrons and positive charges (nucleus was not known at that time) in rigid electron shells of atom which is what called *Plum-pudding* model of atom. He suggested that electrons are arranged in a symmetrical pattern with respect to the center of sphere which is applicable only to smaller elements in periodic table (*Old-timer* wandered a lot after discovering the $e/m$ ratio).

While googling, I found [this applet](http://thomson.phy.syr.edu/thomsonapplet.php) which generates some arbitrary patterns (up to 5000). I think there are many algorithms which can be used to solve these kind of patterns up to some finite value.

Comment: It's not my downvote, but I can see some issues.  If we're looking at a finite # of electrons, the electric field inside the sphere isn't zero perfectly.  I don't know why you say the charges would stick to the surface of a non-conductor.  I'm not sure what it would mean for a non-conductor to have a charge anyway...