# Where should five charges be placed inside a hollow sphere so as the system has the lowest potential energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, electrostatics

I want to know the configuration where the system would be most stable.I only know basic Physics & Maths and cannot start solving the problem.I can understand it for 4 charges and 6 charges as a symmetric configuration of lowest energy is possible. But how do I find out the same for 5 charges?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178328/2451 Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39343/2451

Comment: Hi Enne. Welcome to Phys.SE post. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I understand why this question was closed there. I could have voted to close it myself as "homework without effort". Some one asked the poster: "What have you tried/ how do you plan to go about it?" However, in hindsight, this seems very funny, as it looks like this one-hundred-year-old problem was first solved only 5 years ago:-).

Answer (score 1):

http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.3702 :

"We give a rigorous computer-assisted proof that the triangular bi-pyramid is the unique configuration of 5 points on the 2-sphere that globally minimizes the Coulomb (1/r) potential. We also prove the same result for the (1/r^2) potential. The main mathematical contribution of the paper is a fairly efficient energy estimate that works for any number of points and any power-law potential."

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem

Comment: Thanks. One point that struck my mind is the breach of symmetry to some degree... while 2,3,4,6 all have symmetrical structures.How can this be explained?

Comment: I don't know what configuration of 5 points on a sphere would be more symmetric. By the way, what's the point of giving such assignments to students? As far as I understand, this problem was solved just recently.