$n$ charges inside the ball
Suppose we have $n$ positive charges of magnitude $q$ confined inside a region defined by:
$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$. How will the charges distribute themselves?
Backstory: I read in Griffiths that the free charges in the conductor reside on the surface because the system wants to minimize its potential energy, so it resides on the surface (an example was given of a uniformly charged ball and a spherically charged surface). I was trying to prove this statement for spheres by first analyzing the situation for finite $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then letting $n \to \infty $. However, I don't have any clue how to proceed hence (I was only able to conclude for the case of $3$ particles in 2D, which is an equilateral triangle.) I would be very grateful for any kind of help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem

More on the Thomson problem.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39343/2451 and links therein.

thank you for your help, i did not realize that there were similar questions. sorry!
