# Thomson problem vs. maximizing sum of distance

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy

Given $N$ equally charged points lying on the unit sphere ("electrons"), the Thomson problem consists of finding the configuration of these points such that the electrostatic potential energy

$$
U=k_e\sum_{i<j}\frac{q^2}{|r_i-r_j|} \bigg(\text{normalize to } U=\sum_{i<j}\frac{1}{|r_i-r_j|}\bigg)
$$

is minimized.

Finding such a configuration is an open problem except for some few $N$.

My question is what if one maximizes

$$
U=\sum_{i<j}|r_i-r_j| ?
$$

Q1: Is this a physical concept like the electrostatic potential energy in the other case?

Q2: Is this problem equivalent to the one with $\frac{1}{|r_i-r_j|}$? Is it an open problem?

Q3: In this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35353/sum-total-distance-of-electrons-on-a-spherical-surface) there is a formula for the optimal value of 
$\sum_{i<j}|r_i-r_j|$, namely
$$
U=\sum_{i<j}|r_i-r_j| = \frac{2}{3}N^2R
$$
but I find that this is wrong: Take N=3, then the optimized value should be 6. However, inside a sphere of radius 1, the maximum distance between two points is 2, so the distances must be $d_{1,2}=d_{1,3}=d_{2,3}=2$. This is impossible because $d_{1,2}=d_{2,3}=2$ forces 1 and 3 to be at the opposite point of 2, but then 1 and 3 are at the same point, so $d_{1,3}=0$

Is my counterexample wrong, or is the formula wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I am not sure what you mean, physically it means the maximization of the the distances, but you already knew that.
Q2: it is equivalent, so it is still an open problem.
Q3: the formula does not apply, you are correct, for n=3 the solution is that the electrons reside at the vertices of an equilateral triangle about a great circle. But reading the original question I do not think the author claims that this equation maximizes the distances. Actually he does, I just posted a comment there.